# Formik form returns TypeError when selecting option from react-select list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-select

My formik form returns a TypeError when selecting an option from the multiselect `react-select` list

Inside `<Formik>`, I render the Field as follows:

```
<Field name="type" id="type" as={MultiSelectComponent} options={Types} placeholder="Select Type" />
```

and here is my `MultiSelectComponent`:

```
export const MultiSelectComponent = (props) => {

    return (<Select
        isMulti
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        {...props}
    />)
};
```

the `props` parameter only gives me these props, but no `form` or `field` props.

[image: props parameter]

I get this error whenever I click on an option :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

I passed setFieldValue function prop from `formik` to my custom component by doing so:

```
<Formik 
  ....
>
  {({ isSubmitting, errors, touched, setFieldValue }) => (
  <Form>
    .....
    .....
    <Field
        name="type"
        id="type"
        as={MultiSelectComponent}
        options={Types}
        setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
        placeholder="Select Type"
    />
 </Form>
</Formik>
```

then :

```
export const MultiSelectComponent = ({ options, name, setFieldValue }) => {

    return (<Select
        isMulti
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        options={options}
        onChange={evt =>
            setFieldValue(
                name,
                evt.map(option => option.value)
            )
        }
    />)
};
```